# SVG icon not rendered correctly on resize

Tags: html, css, svg

I have this icon 16x16. When the actual size is set to 13.4x16 (of some environmental reasons) the icon looks blurry. For as much as I understand SVG, it should resize to whatever size I impose on it, nevertheless if I set the preserveAspectRatio attribute. What am I doing wrong here and why doesn't it resize well.

```css
.menu {
  width: 13.4px;
  height: 16px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>SVG icon resize</title>
</head>

<body>
  <svg class="menu" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16" preserveAspectRatio="x16Y16 meet">
    <polygon points="2,6 2,4 14,4 14,6 " />
    <polygon points="2,9 2,7 14,7 14,9 " />
    <polygon points="2,12 2,10 14,10 14,12 " />
  </svg>
</body>

</html>
```

To watch the icon as it should be, set width to 16px.

jsBin for this snippet - [enter link description here](http://jsbin.com/qekigu/edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your `preserveAspectRatio` is not valid.  The list of valid values can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio).

That, itself, is not the cause of your "blurriness" though.  The reason is due to the fact that the reduced size (13.4 vs 16) is causing the SVG to be scaled down by the ratio (13.4/16).  The blurriness is just antialiasing.  The renderer is trying to approximate fractions of a pixel by using grey pixels.

However correct use of `preserveAspectRatio` can help you.  The value you choose will depend on what behaviour you want for the narrower image:

- If you choose `preserveAspectRatio="none"` the icon will be squeezed and stretched to fit the narrow size.  This will look fine for this particular icon, but may not be what you want for other icons.  For example, circles in your icon would become ovals.
- If you want the icon contents to stay the same size but have it centred in the narrow space, try `"xMidYMid slice"`.

Both of these will work for this icon.

- For other icons you may want to keep the left side of the icon and clip off the right hand side.  In this case you might want to use `"xMinYMid slice"`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Regarding the preserveAspectRatio value - that was just a mistake. I tried to test something and probably forgot that the snippet uses as demo, my bad. I think your solution might help with what I need, but it might not always be a good solution to clip a part of the icon. Thanks anyways.